# How can we solve a system of quadratic diophantine equations efficiently unsing Python?

Tags: python, pandas, z3, numerical-methods, diophantine

I am investigating/evaluating technical ways to solve quadratic diophantine systems of equations. My concrete problem can be boiled down into the following two steps:

1. Loading a Textfile that contains lines of tuples `[sqrt(s), sqrt(t), sqrt(u), s, t, u, t+u, t+u-s, t-s]` where each element is an integer. A cutout of this file is given below.
2. For each line in this file: Search an integer quadruple `[w,x,y,z]` that solves the following system of equation: `[x^2-w^2=s]`, `[y^2-w^2=t]`, `[z^2-y^2=u]`, `[z^2-w^2=t+u]`, `[z^2-x^2=t+u-s]` and `[y^2-x^2=t-s]`.

Here is a cutout of the Textfile:

```
520, 533, 756, 270400, 284089, 571536, 855625, 585225, 13689
672, 680, 153, 451584, 462400, 23409, 485809, 34225, 10816
756, 765, 520, 571536, 585225, 270400, 855625, 284089, 13689
612, 740, 2688, 374544, 547600, 7225344, 7772944, 7398400, 173056
644, 725, 2040, 414736, 525625, 4161600, 4687225, 4272489, 110889
```

What I tried so far is to use a `z3` solver, which compiles and runs, but is unfortunatelly slow:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
from z3 import Ints, solve

def main() -> int:
    df = pd.read_csv('tuples.txt', header=None)
    
    tuples = df.to_numpy()

    x, y, z, w = Ints('x y z w')
    for row in tuples:
        s=int(row[3])
        t=int(row[4])
        u=int(row[5])
        solve(x*x-w*w==s, y*y-w*w==t, z*z-y*y==u, w!=0)

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

I would be greatful for any alternative approaches (best practices) to solve such diophantine systems in Python.

Comment: Please always include the [tag:pandas] tag when asking about pandas as described in the [tag:python] tag wiki. pandas introduces a bunch of data structures that aren't native to Python.

Comment: Sorry. Good hint - I just saw that it is fixed. Will consider it next time.

Comment: How can a system of six diophantine equations in four unknowns have solutions ? Where do they come from ?

Comment: This quite interesting question of finding *four squares whose difference each is again a square* originates from [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286376/four-squares-such-that-the-difference-of-any-two-is-a-square/4364401). This question somehow won't let me go.

Answer (score 2):

Created quite huge but very fast solution for you in Python. It should solve much faster than any Mathematica code or `z3`-solver code doing similar stuff. Of course after pre-computations stage, which is done just once and then can be re-used on multiple runs (they save all computed data to cache files).

Following solution does two precomputations. First one takes several minutes, it precomputes 2.7 GB file that is a big filter of squares. This size is tweakable and can be smaller. This file is computed only once (unless you change settings) and re-used on each run. This precomputation is single-core (but after some efforts I can make it multi-core).

Second precomputation takes more time, this one is multi-core, it uses all CPU cores. This precomputation produces quite small file, less than 1 GB even for large params values. This precomputes table which stores all possible Pythagorean Right Triangles with integer sides.

Precomputation is done for all cathetuses smaller than `limit` size. Change current settings `limit = 100_000` to something bigger, probably 1M in your case. If this table is too small then it will fail to find some solutions for large cathetuses. Pre-computed table is also stored on disk and re-used (not computed again) on each run.

This second precomputation calculates following tables of right triangles. It iterates through all possible first integer cathetus A (up to limit) and finds all possible second integer cathetus B (up to limit) such that `A^2 + B^2 = C^2`, where C is also integer. Then for each A it stores a set of B's that satisfy this equation. C is not stored as it can be easily computed out of A and B.

In order to make search of B fast I build two filters. For example we have any integer K0 and K1. We can easily see that if X is a square then X % K0 is a square and so is X % K1. So we can build a table of size K0 such that table[X % K0] is 1 if it is a square mod K0 and 0 otherwise. This gives us a fast filter for remove all such X that are definitely non square (i.e. table[X % K0] is 0). Second K1 filter is used for second stage of extra filtering.

Following Python code can be run straight away, without dependencies, it auotomatically fetches S T U file from your GitHub and caches it on disk.

After two above pre-computations are done all thousands s/t/u solutions are computed within 1-2 seconds. Finally all solutions are stored in JSON format to file `stu_solutions.100000`.

Found Almost Solutions (with non-integer Z) can be dumped by command:

`cat stu_solutions.100000 | grep false`

Found Precise Solutions (with integer Z) can be dumped by command:

`cat stu_solutions.100000 | grep true`

Remaining lines of this file contain either solutions with error (if table was too small for them), or with zero solutions, when w, x, y can't be found. In case of errors you have to build bigger table (second pre-computation), by setting bigger `limit = ...`.

It is necessary to set limit at least as big as `Max(Sqrt(s), Sqrt(t))`. But better to set it several times bigger. Bigger is table higher is chance of finding all possible solutions. Limit needs to be at most as big as biggest possible `w`.

To run following Python code you have to install one time PIP packages `python -m pip install numba numpy requests`.

[Try it online!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow70853194#main.py)

```py
numba = None
import numba

import json, multiprocessing, time, timeit, os, math, numpy as np

if numba is None:
    class NumbaInt:
        def __getitem__(self, key):
            return None
    class numba:
        uint8, uint16, uint32, int64, uint64 = [NumbaInt() for i in range(5)]
        def njit(*pargs, **nargs):
            return lambda f: f
        def prange(*pargs):
            return range(*pargs)
        class types:
            class Tuple:
                def __init__(self, *nargs, **pargs):
                    pass
                def __call__(self, *nargs, **pargs):
                    pass
        class objmode:
            def __init__(self, *pargs, **nargs):
                pass
            def __enter__(self):
                return self
            def __exit__(self, ext, exv, tb):
                pass

@numba.njit(cache = True, parallel = True)
def create_filters():
    Ks = [np.uint32(e) for e in [2 * 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13,    17 * 19 * 23 * 29 * 31 * 37]]
    filts = []
    for i in range(len(Ks)):
        K = Ks[i]
        filt = np.zeros((K,), dtype = np.uint8)
        block = 1 << 25
        nblocks = (K + block - 1) // block
        for j0 in numba.prange(nblocks):
            j = j0 * block
            a = np.arange(j, min(j + block, K)).astype(np.uint64)
            a *= a; a %= K
            filt[a] = 1
        idxs = np.flatnonzero(filt).astype(np.uint32)
        filts.append((K, filt, idxs))
        print(f'filter {i} ratio', round(len(filts[-1][2]) / K, 4))
    return filts

@numba.njit('u2[:, :, :](u4, u4[:])', cache = True, parallel = True, locals = dict(
    t = numba.uint32, s = numba.uint32, i = numba.uint32, j = numba.uint32))
def filter_chain(K, ix):
    assert len(ix) < (1 << 16)
    ix_rev = np.full((K,), len(ix), dtype = np.uint16)
    for i, e in enumerate(ix):
        ix_rev[e] = i
    r = np.zeros((len(ix), K, 2), dtype = np.uint16)
    
    print('filter chain pre-computing...')
    
    for i in numba.prange(K):
        if i % 5000 == 0 or i + 1 >= K:
            with numba.objmode():
                print(f'{i}/{K}, ', end = '', flush = True)
        for j, x in enumerate(ix):
            t, s = i, x
            while True:
                s += 2 * t + 1; s %= K
                t += 1
                if ix_rev[s] < len(ix):
                    assert t - i < (1 << 16)
                    assert t - i < K
                    r[j, i, 0] = ix_rev[s]
                    r[j, i, 1] = np.uint16(t - i)
                    break
    
    print()
    
    return r

def filter_chain_create_load(K, ix):
    fname = f'filter_chain.{K}'
    if not os.path.exists(fname):
        r = filter_chain(K, ix)
        with open(fname, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.tobytes())
    with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
        return np.copy(np.frombuffer(f.read(), dtype = np.uint16).reshape(len(ix), K, 2))

@numba.njit(
    #'void(i8, i8, u4, u1[:], u4[:], u2[:, :, :], u4, u1[:])',
    numba.types.Tuple([numba.uint64[:], numba.uint32[:]])(
        numba.int64, numba.int64, numba.uint32, numba.uint8[:],
        numba.uint32[:], numba.uint16[:, :, :], numba.uint32, numba.uint8[:]),
    cache = True, parallel = True,
    locals = dict(x = numba.uint64, Atpos = numba.uint64, Btpos = numba.uint64, bpos = numba.uint64))
def create_table(limit, cpu_count, k0, f0, fi0, fc0, k1, f1):
    print('Computing tables...')
    
    def gen_squares_candidates_A(cnt, lim, off, t, K, f, fi, fc):
        mark = np.zeros((np.int64(K),), dtype = np.uint8)
        while True:
            start_s = np.int64((np.int64(off) + np.int64(t) ** 2) % K)
            tK = np.uint32(np.int64(t) % np.int64(K))
            if mark[tK]:
                return np.zeros((0,), dtype = np.uint32)
            mark[tK] = 1
            if f[start_s]:
                break
            t += 1
        j = np.int64(np.searchsorted(fi, start_s))
        assert fi[j] == start_s
        r = np.zeros((np.int64(cnt),), dtype = np.uint32)
        r[0] = t
        rpos = np.int64(1)
        tK = np.uint32(np.int64(t) % np.int64(K))
        while True:
            j, dt = fc[j, tK]
            t += dt
            tK += dt
            if tK >= np.uint32(K):
                tK -= np.uint32(K)
            if t >= lim:
                return r[:rpos]
            if np.int64(rpos) >= np.int64(r.shape[0]):
                r = np.concatenate((r, np.zeros_like(r)), axis = 0)
            assert rpos < len(r)
            r[rpos] = t
            rpos += 1
    
    def gen_squares(cnt, lim, off, t, K, f, fi, fc, k1, f1):
        def is_square(x):
            assert x >= 0
            if not f1[np.int64(x) % np.uint32(k1)]:
                return False
            root = np.uint64(math.sqrt(np.float64(x)) + 0.5)
            return root * root == x
        rA = gen_squares_candidates_A(cnt, lim, off, t, K, f, fi, fc)
        r = np.zeros_like(rA)
        rpos = np.int64(0)
        for t in rA:
            if not is_square(np.int64(off) + np.int64(t) ** 2):
                continue
            assert np.int64(rpos) < np.int64(r.shape[0])
            r[rpos] = t
            rpos += 1
        return r[:rpos]
    
    with numba.objmode(gtb = 'f8'):
        gtb = time.time()
    
    search_start = 2
    cnt_limit = max(1 << 4, round(pow(limit, 0.66)))
    
    nblocks2 = cpu_count * 8
    nblocks = nblocks2 * 64
    block = (limit + nblocks - 1) // nblocks
    
    At = np.zeros((limit + 1,), dtype = np.uint64)
    Bt = np.zeros((0,), dtype = np.uint32)
    Atpos, Btpos = search_start + 1, 0
    
    with numba.objmode(tb = 'f8'):
        tb = time.time()
    for iMblock in range(0, nblocks, nblocks2):
        cur_blocks = min(nblocks, iMblock + nblocks2) - iMblock
        As = np.zeros((cur_blocks, block), dtype = np.uint64)
        As_size = np.zeros((cur_blocks,), dtype = np.uint64)
        Bs = np.zeros((cur_blocks, 1 << 16,), dtype = np.uint32)
        Bs_size = np.zeros((cur_blocks,), dtype = np.uint64)
        for iblock in numba.prange(cur_blocks):
            iblock0 = iMblock + iblock
            begin, end = max(search_start, iblock0 * block), min(limit, (iblock0 + 1) * block)
            begin = min(begin, end)
            #a = np.zeros((block,), dtype = np.uint64)
            #b = np.zeros((1 << 10,), dtype = np.uint32)
            bpos = 0
            for ix, x in enumerate(range(begin, end)):
                s = gen_squares(cnt_limit, limit, x ** 2, search_start, k0, f0, fi0, fc0, k1, f1)
                assert not (np.int64(bpos) + np.int64(s.shape[0]) > np.int64(Bs[iblock].shape[0]))
                #while np.int64(bpos) + np.int64(s.shape[0]) > np.int64(b.shape[0]):
                #    b = np.concatenate((b, np.zeros_like(b)), axis = 0)
                bpos_end = bpos + s.shape[0]
                Bs[iblock, bpos : bpos_end] = s
                As[iblock, ix] = bpos_end
                bpos = bpos_end
            As_size[iblock] = end - begin
            Bs_size[iblock] = bpos
        for iblock, (cA, cB) in enumerate(zip(As, Bs)):
            cA = cA[:As_size[iblock]]
            cB = cB[:Bs_size[iblock]]
            assert Atpos + cA.shape[0] <= At.shape[0]
            prevA = At[Atpos - 1]
            for e in cA:
                At[Atpos] = prevA + e
                Atpos += 1
            #while np.int64(Btpos) + np.int64(cB.shape[0]) > np.int64(Bt.shape[0]):
                #Bt = np.concatenate((Bt, np.zeros_like(Bt)), axis = 0)
                #Bt = np.concatenate((Bt, np.zeros(Bt.shape, dtype = np.uint32)), axis = 0)
            #assert np.int64(Btpos) + np.int64(cB.shape[0]) <= np.int64(Bt.shape[0])
            #assert cB.shape[0] > 0
            #Bt[Btpos : Btpos + cB.shape[0]] = cB
            Bt = np.concatenate((Bt, cB))
            #Btpos += cB.shape[0]
            #assert At[Atpos - 1] == Btpos
            assert At[Atpos - 1] == Bt.shape[0]
        with numba.objmode(tim = 'f8'):
            tim = max(0.001, round(time.time() - tb, 3))
        print(f'{str(min(limit, (iMblock + cur_blocks) * block) >> 10).rjust(len(str(limit >> 10)))}/{limit >> 10} K, ELA',
            round(tim / 60.0, 1), 'min, ETA', round((nblocks - (iMblock + cur_blocks)) * (tim / (iMblock + cur_blocks)) / 60.0, 1), 'min')
    
    assert Atpos == At.shape[0]
    
    with numba.objmode(gtb = 'f8'):
        gtb = time.time() - gtb
    
    print(f'Tables sizes: A {Atpos}, B {Bt.shape[0]}')
    print('Time elapsed computing tables:', round(gtb / 60.0, 1), 'min')
    
    return At, Bt
    
def table_create_load(limit, *pargs):
    fnameA = f'right_triangles_table.A.{limit}'
    fnameB = f'right_triangles_table.B.{limit}'
    if not os.path.exists(fnameA) or not os.path.exists(fnameB):
        A, B = create_table(limit, *pargs)
        with open(fnameA, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(A.tobytes())
        with open(fnameB, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(B.tobytes())
        del A, B
    with open(fnameA, 'rb') as f:
        A = np.copy(np.frombuffer(f.read(), dtype = np.uint64))
        assert A.shape[0] == limit + 1, (fnameA, A.shape[0], limit + 1)
    with open(fnameB, 'rb') as f:
        B = np.copy(np.frombuffer(f.read(), dtype = np.uint32))
        assert A[-1] == B.shape[0], (fnameB, A[-1], B.shape[0])
    print(f'Table A size {A.shape[0]}, B size {B.shape[0]}')
    return A, B

def find_solutions(tA, tB, stu):
    def is_square(x):
        root = np.uint64(math.sqrt(np.float64(x)) + 0.5)
        return bool(root * root == x), int(root)
    
    assert tA[-1] == tB.shape[0]
    
    fname = f'stu_solutions.{tA.shape[0] - 1}'
    with open(fname, 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as fout:
        for s, t, u in stu:
            s, t, u = map(int, (s, t, u))
            r = {'stu': [s, t, u]}
            if s + 1 >= tA.shape[0]:
                r['err'] = f's {s} exceeds table A len {tA.shape[0]}'
            elif t + 1 >= tA.shape[0]:
                r['err'] = f't {t} exceeds table A len {tA.shape[0]}'
            else:
                r['res'] = []
                bs = tB[tA[s] : tA[s + 1]]
                ts = tB[tA[t] : tA[t + 1]]
                for w in np.intersect1d(bs, ts):
                    w = int(w)
                    x2 = s ** 2 + w ** 2
                    y2 = t ** 2 + w ** 2
                    x_isq, x = is_square(x2)
                    assert x_isq, (s, t, u, w, x2)
                    y_isq, y = is_square(y2)
                    assert y_isq, (s, t, u, w, x2, y2)
                    z2 = u ** 2 + y2
                    z_isq, z = is_square(z2)
                    r['res'].append({
                        'w': w,
                        'x': x,
                        'y': y,
                        'z2': z2,
                        'z2_is_square': z_isq,
                        'z': z if z_isq else math.sqrt(z2),
                    })
            fout.write(json.dumps(r, ensure_ascii = False) + '\n')
    
    print(f'STU solutions written to {fname}')

def solve(limit):
    import requests
    
    filts = create_filters()
    fc0 = filter_chain_create_load(filts[0][0], filts[0][2])
    
    tA, tB = table_create_load(limit, multiprocessing.cpu_count(),
        filts[0][0], filts[0][1], filts[0][2], fc0, filts[1][0], filts[1][1])
    
    # https://github.com/Sultanow/pythagorean/blob/main/data/pythagorean_stu_Arty_.txt?raw=true
    ifname = 'pythagorean_stu_Arty_.txt'
    iurl = f'https://github.com/Sultanow/pythagorean/blob/main/data/{ifname}?raw=true'
    if not os.path.exists(ifname):
        print(f'Downloading: {iurl}')
        data = requests.get(iurl).content
        with open(ifname, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(data)
    stu = []
    with open(ifname, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
        for line in f:
            if not line.strip():
                continue
            if 'elapsed' in line:
                continue
            s, t, u, *_ = eval(f'[{line}]')
            stu.append([s, t, u])
    print(f'Read {len(stu)} s/t/u tuples')
    find_solutions(tA, tB, stu)
    
def main():
    limit = 100_000
    solve(limit)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
filter 0 ratio 0.0224
filter 1 ratio 0.0199
Table A size 100001, B size 371720
Read 27060 s/t/u tuples
STU solutions written to stu_solutions.100000
```

Examples of all found Almost-solutions (where only Z is not integer) for 50K limit:

```
{"stu": [3528, 37128, 10175], "res": [{"w": 31654, "x": 31850, "y": 48790, "z2": 2483994725, "z2_is_square": false, "z": 49839.69025786577}]}
{"stu": [7700, 12155, 5460], "res": [{"w": 10608, "x": 13108, "y": 16133, "z2": 290085289, "z2_is_square": false, "z": 17031.89035309939}]}
{"stu": [9405, 12155, 10608], "res": [{"w": 5460, "x": 10875, "y": 13325, "z2": 290085289, "z2_is_square": false, "z": 17031.89035309939}]}
{"stu": [11760, 18564, 31977], "res": [{"w": 13475, "x": 17885, "y": 22939, "z2": 1548726250, "z2_is_square": false, "z": 39353.8594041296}]}
{"stu": [14364, 18564, 13475], "res": [{"w": 31977, "x": 35055, "y": 36975, "z2": 1548726250, "z2_is_square": false, "z": 39353.8594041296}]}
{"stu": [15400, 24310, 10920], "res": [{"w": 21216, "x": 26216, "y": 32266, "z2": 1160341156, "z2_is_square": false, "z": 34063.78070619878}]}
{"stu": [18480, 29172, 13104], "res": [{"w": 21175, "x": 28105, "y": 36047, "z2": 1471101025, "z2_is_square": false, "z": 38354.93481939449}]}
{"stu": [18810, 24310, 21216], "res": [{"w": 10920, "x": 21750, "y": 26650, "z2": 1160341156, "z2_is_square": false, "z": 34063.78070619878}]}
{"stu": [21840, 43500, 30800], "res": [{"w": 14651, "x": 26299, "y": 45901, "z2": 3055541801, "z2_is_square": false, "z": 55276.95542448046}]}
{"stu": [22572, 29172, 21175], "res": [{"w": 13104, "x": 26100, "y": 31980, "z2": 1471101025, "z2_is_square": false, "z": 38354.93481939449}]}
{"stu": [23100, 36465, 16380], "res": [{"w": 31824, "x": 39324, "y": 48399, "z2": 2610767601, "z2_is_square": false, "z": 51095.67105929816}]}
{"stu": [23520, 37128, 63954], "res": [{"w": 26950, "x": 35770, "y": 45878, "z2": 6194905000, "z2_is_square": false, "z": 78707.7188082592}]}
{"stu": [28215, 36465, 31824], "res": [{"w": 16380, "x": 32625, "y": 39975, "z2": 2610767601, "z2_is_square": false, "z": 51095.67105929816}]}
{"stu": [30800, 48620, 21840], "res": [{"w": 42432, "x": 52432, "y": 64532, "z2": 4641364624, "z2_is_square": false, "z": 68127.56141239755}]}
{"stu": [36960, 37128, 31654], "res": [{"w": 10175, "x": 38335, "y": 38497, "z2": 2483994725, "z2_is_square": false, "z": 49839.69025786577}]}
{"stu": [37620, 43500, 14651], "res": [{"w": 30800, "x": 48620, "y": 53300, "z2": 3055541801, "z2_is_square": false, "z": 55276.95542448046}]}
{"stu": [37620, 48620, 42432], "res": [{"w": 21840, "x": 43500, "y": 53300, "z2": 4641364624, "z2_is_square": false, "z": 68127.56141239755}]}
```